# Can I have two addresses for the same heroku application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I already have a Rails 4 application and everything is working fine. I want to know if I can have another heroku address, that will redirect to this same app. Please enlighten if it is possible and how so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You have two options:

1. handle the redirect in the Heroku app

   In this case, you need to point both domains to the same application at your current DNS provider. Also, you need to add both domains to the Heroku application using the `heroku domains:add` command.

   Finally, you need to handle the redirect inside the application. In the router, add a route constrainted to the hostname you want to redirect, and use the [Rails `redirect` feature](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html) to manage the redirect.

   More complex redirects can be achieved with a Rack middleware mounted on your Rails application
2. Redirect using a redirect feature provided by your domain registration or DNS provider. Most registrars provide the ability to redirect a domain to another one. In that case, use the feature to redirect to the primary domain.

   You will not need to change anything at Heroku.

If you want to have the same codebase deployed to 2 Heroku apps, use their ["environment"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) feature instead which essentially configures each environment as a different Heroku git remote.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your answer. But I do not have a domain name currently. I want an application at something.herokuapp.com to be also accessible via someother.herokuapp.com . Can you help me with that?

Comment: Well, then simply deploy the same codebase to 2 heroku apps. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments (the example shows 2 environments, but you can have the same environment deployed to multiple apps using the same "environment" principle.

Comment: Deploying the same code base kinds of breaks the application when on clicking the devise confirmation link received in the mail. It reverts back to the other application. And also the same users won't be available for signup if I use two different applications.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can't have the same app served on two different Heroku names, unless you deploy the application twice.

Comment: I came up with a dirty hack, where I made another application, and simply redirected the root of this new application to my old one. I wish I could have done something proper. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you just want to redirect (eg: something.com redirects to another.com), you need to do it on your dns provider (usually your domain registrar). When setting up your DNS, you should have a way to add a URL record.

If you want to use the same app with different domains, you need to configure your DNS to "point" to heroku and [add the domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) using `heroku domains:add` command. Note that you may need to change your code to dynamically handle different domains, particularly with mailers as you may need to send e-mails with a different sender address (FROM) or with different activation urls in case you have a registration process with e-mail confirmation. ActionDispatch::Request has a few useful methods like `request.host`.

Comment: I do not have a DNS address or a domain name bought currently. I just want something.herokuapp.com to be redirected to someother.herokuapp.com. Is it feasible?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You can deploy a index.php file (no need to use a rails app) with the following header: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http:// someother.herokuapp.com">`. I'm not sure if heroku support just plain html. For rails static sites, you can read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby
`

Comment: Just to make myself clear, the redirect solution should be deployed in the source app (something).